# Scrollview Image Does Not Zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

i make an application that contain Scrollview and Scrollview Contain array Of images i want to make a zoom my imageview image then i write method viewForZoomingInScrollView but it is not working here code for that is

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
 for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
 {
     return [self.zoomScroll.subviews objectAtIndex:index];
 }
return nil;
 }
```

and i set Scrollview Delegate and Minimum and Maximum Zooming Scale and Here my Scrollview And imagevew Size is

```
bigImage.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
bigImage.frame=CGRectMake(index * self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);

CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width*[self.objectarray count], self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    [self.zoomScroll setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
```

Here bigImage is my Imageview and zoomScroll is my Scrollview I make this code but Scrollview image is not zoomed please give me Solution i am Confused for this Question.

Comment: you are using for loop so at end of viewForZoomingInScrollView: function your index = imagesa.count so it return nil object and thats why your image is not zooming

Comment: but when i not use direct return bigimage then it is not also zoomed.

Comment: for that you have to store index of current image than return only one view at current index

Comment: I not understand what you say.

Comment: just return yourImageView in  viewForZoomingInScrollView

Comment: #Saurabh Prajapati when i return my imageview and when i zoom then it is not Scrolled to next image. so i confuse about that.

Comment: I think that your values for zoom control from viewForZoomingInScrollView is not passing to "bigImage.bounds" and "bigImage.frame". You should declare the index variable globally because now it's scope is only limited to for loop.

Comment: Okh bro i will try it.

Comment: Bro i will try it but it was not working.